# Convert Windows file to Linux file

Tags: java, linux, file, unix, file-conversion

I am having trouble with Windows files running as part of a shell script on a Linux box and I was wondering if it is possible to "convert" a Windows created file to a Linux one using Java or possibly a Linux command?

For example:

If I upload a CSV file created in Windows, then on the server using `nano` I can see the file was saved in DOS Format. I can toggle between DOS and Linux format using `M-D` and save it as a Linux file.

My question is whether it is possible to achieve this via Java (<-preference) or through a Linux command?

I have tried stripping carriage returns `sed -i 's/{ctrl-v}{ctrl-m}//g' [file]` but this does not help with the issue.

Comment: Do you know in advance if a file will be a linux or a windows file?

Comment: There are a couple of commands to to this.  `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` strip and add crs respectively.  You can also use `tr` to delete cr characters with `tr -d \015`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`dos2unix` and `unix2dos` unix commands, from the `dos2unix` package.

Comment: These commands are called fromdos and todos under ubuntu , if you can't find them under their original names.

Comment: Thanks - was what I needed. Also @Disco - I needed that information :)

Answer (score 4):

if you don't have dos2unix utility available but you have **vim** or **vi** installed

open your file:

`vi yourfile.csv` or `vim yourfile.csv`

To change the file format to unix type:

`:setlocal ff=unix`

Then save the file:

`:wq!`

*Reference: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_Format*

Comment: This answer deserves much more votes as it doesn't require any package installation. +1 for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BufferedReader with a contained FileReader to get the File line by line and then do whatever you want with that lines (e.G. push them into another File that has the correct line endings.

```
File relFile = new File(".....");
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(relFile));
File targetFile = new File("....");
FileWriter fwri = new FileWriter(targetFile);
String line;
while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
    fwri.write(line+"\n"); // if you want the system line delimiter use the System property for that.
}
fwri.flush();
fwri.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use vim to check your encoding format:

```
:set fileencoding
```

in windows, it is normally gb2312, but in linux it is utf-8.

So you'd better to convert it to linux format by following method:

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
```

and then save it by `:wq!`